# Time complexity of typecasting dictionary to list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

If we have a dictionary with 'n' key-value pairs, then, does typecasting it to a list a linear time operation (i.e. O(n))?

Comment: Have you tried profiling it? Please do, and report the results if they are not what you would expect.

Comment: What do you mean with typecasting? Could you show a sample code representing the desired operation?

Comment: From https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity: *Iteration[2]: O(n)*. So yes, it is linear (with caveats about deleted entries, see the link).

Comment: And you are not *type casting* anything. You are *creating a list from an iterable*, and that iterable happens to be a dictionary. Iteration over a dictionary produces the keys, so you are *creating a list containing all the keys*.

Comment: @MSeifert, **print list(dicta)** is the desired operation. Here, dicta is a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by "typecasting it to a list". `list(d)` will return a list of the dictionary's keys. `list(d.items())` will return a list of key/value pairs.

Either way, yes, it's O(n). It can't be *faster* than O(n) since it obviously has to iterate over all of the dictionary items. And there's no reason it would be slower than O(n).

Comment: It's **not** O(n). Otherwise all these cases with constant n = 1 would take about the same constant time instead of doubling the time: https://ideone.com/yPMLt7

Comment: @StefanPochmann: yes, you can produce a pathological case by creating an enormous number of keys and then deleting most.

Comment: This is a difference between *typical* time complexity and *worst-case* time complexity.